# What are the limitations using DACPAC in SQL Server deployment

Tags: sql-server-2019

I'm exploring the DACPAC feature on the SQL Server database deployments.

I'm using the `EXTRACT` action to get the DACPAC generated from the source and the `PUBLISH` action to deploy it to the target.

**Extract**

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:Extract /SourceDatabaseName:%sourcedatabaseName% /SourceServerName:%sourceserverName% /TargetFile:%FilePath%
```

**Publish**

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:%SourceFile% /TargetServerName:%serverName% /TargetDatabaseName:%databaseName%
```

Here, when I have new columns introduced in the source table when I do the DACPAC deployment, it works fine. The new columns are reflected in the target.

But, when I drop columns in the source and do the DACPAC deployment, the changes are not reflected. The column is not getting dropped in the target. Is it because I have data in that column?

In the other scenario, I have some test tables and test stored procedures in the source, when I generate DACPAC and do the deployment the same test tables and stored procedures are getting deployed in the target. Is there a way to restrict this?

So would like to understand what are all the limitations of using DACPAC?

Using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: You may have to set the option: `/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false`

Comment: No errors, deployment is success

Comment: Thanks, @LukaszSzozda. /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false is worked on the colum removal case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column removal from non-empty table could lead to data loss.

It could be overriden with: `/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false`

[DacDeployOptions.BlockOnPossibleDataLoss Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacdeployoptions.blockonpossibledataloss?view=sql-dacfx-150)

> Get or set boolean that specifies whether deployment should stop if the operation could cause data loss.
>
> True to stop deployment if possible data loss if detected; otherwise, false. **Default is true.**